# Error In API cURL Call: {"errors":{"price_rule":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

Tags: php, laravel, shopify-app

I am getting an error in cURL call for Price rule based on selected products.
Following is my error:

```
{
   "errors":{
      "price_rule":"Required parameter missing or invalid"
   }
}
```

Following is my body parameters which I am sending in cURL call:

```
{
   "price_rule":{
      "title":"sss",
      "target_type":"line_item",
      "target_selection":"entitled",
      "allocation_method":"across",
      "value_type":"fixed_amount",
      "value":"-434",
      "customer_selection":"all",
      "prerequisite_quantity_range":{
         "greater_than_or_equal_to":"2"
      },
      "entitled_product_ids":{
         "0":"2397130326093",
         "1":"2397129965645",
         "2":"2397131898957",
         "3":"2397132324941"
      },
      "starts_at":"2019-02-22T08:08:53.000Z"
   }
}
```

Following is my cURL call:

```
$ch = curl_init();    
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($newrule));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $access_token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($pro_ids11));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Shopify-Access-Token: '.$shops_token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
if (isset($error_msg)) {
    echo $error_msg;
}
```

Please note that I am working in PHP.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @cbaconnier any solution for this error?

Comment: `entitled_product_ids` is an object, but in the [the doc](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/discounts/pricerule#create) it's an array

Comment: @VikasGhai, could you add the code where you try to access the response

Comment: @mooga, please check my cURL request above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you change your code like this

```
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'My New Shopify App v.1');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

    // Setup headers
    $request_headers[] = "X-Shopify-Access-Token: " . $token;
    $request_headers[]='Content-Type: application/json'

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);  
    $query = json_encode($query);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Yes, My Above code is also running very well in postman. but when I try this using cURL it gives me error.

Comment: @VikasGhai updated my answer can you change your code like i did

Comment: It return me NULL in response.

Comment: {"price_rule":{"title":"erere","target_type":"line_item","target_selection":"entitled","allocation_method":"across","value_type":"fixed_amount","value":"-232","customer_selection":"all","prerequisite_quantity_range":{"greater_than_or_equal_to":"2"},"entitled_product_ids":["2389483225165","2397130326093","2397129965645","2397132324941"],"starts_at":"2019-02-22T09:52:35.2019-02-22T09:52:35+00:00Z"}}
-----------------
Following is my result variable.
null

Comment: check in price rule created or not ? @VikasGhai

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188877/discussion-between-vikas-ghai-and-jigar-halani).

Answer (score 2):

Your format is wrong: `entitled_product_ids` should be an array and not an object

```
"entitled_collection_ids": [
    2397130326093,
    2397129965645,
    2397131898957,
    2397132324941
],
```

Documentation for reference: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/discounts/pricerule#create

Comment: I have already tried with following code:

"entitled_product_ids":
[
      "2389483225165",
      "2397130326093",
      "2397129965645",
      "2397131898957"
],

But I got same error again:
{"errors":{"price_rule":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

Comment: `"2389483225165", "2397130326093", "2397129965645", "2397131898957"` should be int, not string according to the documentation

Comment: let me try with Integer.

Comment: No Luck:

{"price_rule":{"title":"ggg","target_type":"line_item","target_selection":"entitled","allocation_method":"across","value_type":"fixed_amount","value":"-343","customer_selection":"all","prerequisite_quantity_range":{"greater_than_or_equal_to":"3"},"entitled_product_ids":[2397130326093,2397132324941,2397133176909],"starts_at":"2019-02-22T10:09:46.2019-02-22T10:09:46+00:00Z"}}
{"errors":{"price_rule":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

Comment: Thanks for your Efforts too :) (Y)

Answer (score 1):

First : You need to send the data with `'Content-Type: application/json'` and be sure of that

Second : You have to send `entitled_product_ids` as an array not an object

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Shopify-Access-Token: '.$shops_token, 
'Content-Type: application/json'));

"entitled_product_ids": [
  2397130326093,
  2397129965645,
  2397131898957,
  2397131898957
]
```

Comment: I have tried and got following error now:

{"error":"822: unexpected token at '=%7B%22price_rule%..............}

Comment: @VikasGhai convert the `price_rule` object to string

Answer (score 0):

entitled_product_ids should be in this format:

```
      "entitled_product_ids":{
         2397130326093,
         2397129965645,
         2397131898957,
         2397132324941
      },
```

Also, the starts_at value should be in the ISO 8601 format (Note that one 0 is missing at the end):

```
"starts_at":"2019-02-22T08:08:53.00Z"
```

Comment: I have used  $cur_date=date('Y-m-d').'T'.date("H:i:s").'.'.date("v").'Z'; for date format.

Comment: @VikasGhai You can use `date('c').'Z';`

Comment: Okay Let me try with this.

Comment: I have changed and got this:
"starts_at":"2019-02-22T09:22:48.2019-02-22T09:22:48+00:00Z"}}

{"errors":{"price_rule":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

Comment: `2019-02-22T09:22:48.2019-02-22T09:22:48+00:00Z`?? Let me rephrase that: You can use  `$cur_ate = date('c').'Z';`